# How can I proper date time value from unix time?

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

UNIX Timestamp

```
  1262304000
  1224633600
  940636800
  939772800
  1332288000
  1096934400
  1088121600    
   ...
```

1.Try

```
frmt_date = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1088121600).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
```

Those results of time value were `00:00`.

(result)

```
 2012-10-11 00:00
 2004-04-20 00:00
 1999-01-07 00:00
 ....
```

2. Try

   ```
    def xldate_to_datetime(xldate):
    temp = dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    delta = dt.timedelta(days=xldate)
    return temp+delta
    ts = "1262304000"
    tsxl = ((int(ts)/60)/60)/24 + 25569
    readabledate =  xldate_to_datetime(tsxl)
    print(readabledate)
   ```

results of time value were all `00:00`, though.

How can I get proper time from those UNIX https://i.stack.imgur.com/khDmi.jpg

Comment: If all of your timestamps correspond to 00:00 GMT, it's no surprise that you get 00:00 for the time. What is your question exactly?

Comment: You seem to be so sure these results are wrong. What other results did you expect?

Comment: The results corresponds to the values. You can check it: dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dt.datetime.now().timestamp()).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach

```
>>> mytime =  1332288000
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> frmt_date = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(mytime).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
>>> print(frmt_date)
2012/03/21 00:00
>>> mytime =  mytime + 10000
>>> frmt_date = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(mytime).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
>>> print(frmt_date)
2012/03/21 02:46
```

So, your date times were indeed at 00:00

Answer (score 3):

The conversions are all correct.

The timestamps all happened to be seconds from the midnight of January 01, 1970 whose `mod (3600 * 24)` are 0 i.e. all the timestamps correspond to the midnight of some date in UTC.

You can quickly confirm this without actually converting to datetime objects with:

```
assert all(t % 86400 == 0 for t in timestamps)
```

Comment: Side note: according wikiepdia page for leap seconds : the 86400 seconds / day is due to POSIX standard but it is inconsistent with UTC dates. There were lots of leap seconds since 1970, so I'm having doubts concerning the consistency of the 86400 sec/day check for an exact midnight UTC date representation.(Maybe I'm overthinking it)

Comment: @LoneWanderer True. UTC is strictly increasing while Unix time is not. However, since leap seconds do not augur well with deterministic time-stamping in programming, Unix has a slight adjustment to help manage this: *unix time is not a true representation of UTC, as a leap second in UTC shares the same Unix time as the second which came before it* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time. So 86400 should work well here.